# How can i set webhook for telegram bot by python?

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I'm writing a telegram bot with python, it works very fine by the getupdate method.I want to execute it by setwebhook.I use telepot library in my bot code.I have SSL and host for my bot.please help me how can I set webhook on my bot.
when I type request string in the browser the output is:
my request string:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot[token]/getWebHookInfo
```

and output is:

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https://myserver/test.py","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":0,"max_connections":40}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a http server service on Python, `.py` file is plain text, won't execute by server.

Comment: my server execute .py files

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a **web server** and **set url** to receive requests.
Telegram bot sends **POST https** requests to your server with configured url to ports **443, 80, 88 or 8443**.

When you set up url to receive requests you need to set a webhook: send a command to your telegram bot so that configure it to send all messages to your server and url that you have set up. To do this you need to send a request to the url `https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/setWebhook` with parameters: `url , certificate, max_connections` etc. Where `url` is your server url that is ready to receive messages from the bot. More details here https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook